# Adding objects to new .blend files using python

Tags: python, scripting, collections

I want to save a number of objects of my project file to a new external .blend file using python.

```
 filepath = bpy.context.scene.custompath
 data_blocks = set(bpy.data.collections)

 # write collection to new blend file
 bpy.data.libraries.write(filepath, data_blocks)
```

The above code works fine when running the full script for the first time. Repeating it with a second or third object, seems to overwrite the existing content.
When opening the created file, Blender tells me that some libraries were not loaded.

[image]

The outliner of the file that the collections where saved to looks like this:

[image]

It displays only the last collection which was written into the file. The first two collections are missing library paths (I don't understand why, it looks like the file is linking to itself).

So my question is:
Is there a way to tell Blender to **add** the collections - one at a time - to the existing ones in the created file when using `bpy.data.libraries.write`?